# Using qsort to output ordered list

Tags: c++, qsort

I have an assignment in my C++ course to get information from a text file that says this:

```
Scores.txt

PhredrickTheGreat     5.7 5.3 5.1 5.0 4.7 4.8 
RobbieTheRock         3.1 4.9 4.1 3.7 4.6 3.9 
CannonBallKelly       4.1 5.3 4.9 4.4 3.9 5.4 
MartyTheMissile       5.1 5.7 5.6 5.5 4.4 5.3 
BillieBomb            5.9 4.8 5.5 5.0 5.7 5.7 
JackKnifeJake         5.1 4.7 4.1 3.1 4.6 5.0 
Splash                5.1 5.1 4.9 3.4 5.5 5.3 
MillyTheMalard        4.9 4.3 5.2 4.5 4.6 4.9 
HoraceTheDivingHorse  6.0 6.0 5.7 5.8 5.9 5.9 
FishTank              4.3 5.2 5.9 5.3 4.3 6.0
```

These are the names of fictional baseball players (and batting scores?). The program should output the names of the players, their average score, and then assign them 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. place based on their average score. Here's what I have so far:

[image]

I commented out a couple of "couts," so you can ignore those.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Scores
{
    float Score;
    string Name;
};

float calculateAverage(float RawData){ return RawData / 6.0;}

int main()
{
    string Name;
    string Score;
    float RawScores = 0;
    float Average;

    Scores ComScores[10];

    ifstream playerData("Scores.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        playerData >> Name; // Read in a name
        //cout << left << setw(25) << Name << " ";
        ComScores[i].Name = Name;

        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) // Read in Six Scores
        {
            playerData >> Score;
            RawScores += atof(Score.c_str());
            //cout << Score << " ";
        }
        Average = calculateAverage(RawScores);
        ComScores[i].Score = Average;
    RawScores = 0;
    //cout << " Ave: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << Average <<endl;
    }

    cout << "Place      Name               Score\n";
    cout << "-------------------------------------\n";



    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i < 9){
            cout << " " << i+1 << " " << setw(25) << ComScores[i].Name << " " << setw(8) << ComScores[i].Score << endl;
        }
        else{cout << i+1 << " " << setw(25) << ComScores[i].Name << " " << setw(8) << ComScores[i].Score << endl;}
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm almost done I just have to order the places with qsort. My professor gave us one example of using qsort (which I can post), but it didn't really relate to this program (in my point of view). The programs already kinda big and complicated to a novice like me, so, I'm having trouble implementing qsort.

What can I add to my program to sort the last "for loop" to order the list?

I will answer any questions asap.

Comment: `qsort` is kinda not so great at all. It would be nice if your professor would allow you to use `std::sort` since this is C++.

Comment: he won't allow it :/

Comment: I love it when profs teach the wrong way to do C++.

Comment: and he hasn't even lectured on arrays yet...

Comment: Yes, the prof is not very C++ savvy. If all you're getting out of C++ is `cout` ...

Comment: well on an example program, before the for loop, it said "qsort((void*)Divers, 10, sizeof(Divers[0]),NumberCompare);" before the for loop that sorted the various couts

Comment: off the topic, how do you highlight code text in the comments?

Comment: I'm gonna post a sample program he used in class and I hope it helps (someone)

Comment: Surround the text-to-be-highlighted-as-code by backticks "\`". And you may want to read up on `qsort` man page: http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/qsort.3.html

Comment: hmm the backticks aren't working ''testing 123''

Comment: @Zack the backticks are those ```````` not the "" !

Comment: Your professor is just plain *wrong* when you are asked to use `qsort` on your array of objects.  It isn't a matter of opinion, it is plain *wrong*.  Please see this page:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort  and read the `Notes` section:  `The type of the elements of the array must be a trivial type, otherwise the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: @Zack So your professor is teaching you not only "bad C++", but just wrong things that are not guaranteed to work correctly.  Please direct your teacher to the page I linked to, which says in black and white why usage of `qsort` cannot be used on your `Scores` struct.

Comment: I feel a little uncomfortable challenging my professor, but I do agree with you. So, I will consider emailing him that anonymously.

Comment: aw, why the down-vote?

Comment: Not sure if your assignment allows it, but you could read score directly into a float and skip the conversion from string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you could do the comparison function :

```
int score_cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const Scores* sa = (const Scores*)a;
    const Scores* sb = (const Scores*)b;

    if (sa->Score > sb->Score)
        return -1;
    else if (sb->Score > sa->Score)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

And you would call `qsort` like this:

```
qsort((void*)ComScores, 10, sizeof(Scores), score_cmp);
```

That said, you should try to rewrite it yourself once you understand how it's supposed to work, it's not very hard and it's a good exercise.

**But** note that as @PaulMcKenzie pointed out, calling qsort with a non-trivial type is **undefined behavior**.
If you must use qsort, a simple but fairly ugly fix would be to replace the `string` member in `struct Scores` by a `string*` and then update the remaining code as needed (the qsort part would not have to change).

Comment: I'm getting an error message: "a function definition is not allowed here before the '{' token." I copied your code, putting the function "score_cmp" below everything, I put the "qsort" line before my last for loop, and I made a prototype for the ''score_cmp'' function by just copy and pasted the first line of the "score_cmp" function and adding a semicolon

Comment: I will take your advice and try to recreate it myself, but I want to make sure I can get it to compile first.

Comment: @Zack you probably put it in the wrong place. Perhaps there's a missing `}` somewhere. If you put it above the main, it should work.

Comment: @Zack well, you put that function *inside main*! You can't do that, function have to be at the top-level. The compiler was pretty explicit too. Look where `calculateAverage` is for example, it's not in main but above. Under would work too but you'd need a prototype.

Comment: crap. didn't mean to do that

Comment: @Zack feel free to accept the answer if that's all you need.

Comment: @tux3 See my comment in the original post.  Usage of `qsort` on non-trivial types is undefined behavior.  The `Scores` has a `std::string` object, thus it isn't a trivial type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Indeed, it should really be fixed, and that's going to make the code significantly more complicated. I hope that professor has a good reason for doing that.